# How to connect to Microsoft Project Online using python

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, ms-project

I have hundreds of projects hosted on Microsoft Project Online and I want to perform the analysis using Python. How to connect to Microsoft Project Online?

Currently I am using PowerBI but I am not liking it and want to use Python for the analysis.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?